# Cannot view images when viewing ionic app on android phone

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When I tried running my app using `ionic run --device` the images under **/www/img** does not seem to appear correctly. Here's my current setup

`Cordova CLI: 5.0.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.8.11
Gulp local:   Local version 3.8.11
Ionic Version: 1.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.4.5
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.0.22
OS: Distributor ID: elementary OS Description:  elementary OS Freya 
Node Version: v0.12.2`

Here's the code snippet:

```
<ion-view view-title="My Account">
 <ion-content>
    <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-avatar">
        <img src="/img/profile-img.jpg">
        <h2>Marty McFly</h2>
        <p>janedoe@mail.com</p>
        <button class="button button-clear icon ion-android-more-vertical signout" ng-click="openPopover($event)"></button>
      </div>
   </ion-content>
```

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: It would be better to show some code, maybe.

Comment: @LeftyX Added a code snippet

Comment: As I said it should be: `img/profile-img.jpg` so your tag should be `<img src="img/profile-img.jpg">`.

Comment: `img/profile-img.jpg` still doesn't work. Also, using `img/profile-img.jpg` doesn't work even when running `ionic serve`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you reference your image?

You can do this:

```
<img ng-src="img/myimage.png" />
```

or

```
<img src="img/myimage.png" />
```

and if the image comes from a model:

```
<img ng-src="{{image}}" />
```

or

```
<img ng-src="{{vm.image}}" />
```

Comment: All of them doesn't seem to work. And the link is `/img/myImage.png`. img/myImage wont render

Comment: Okay, nvm. It seems that I just need to remove my $locationProvider. Thanks man.

Comment: I was just wondering. Have made a few tests and it seemed ok.

Comment: Anyway, glad I've helped ... a bit. You can always upvote me if you like ;-)

Answer (score 0):

also found bug . remove "-" from your image name and use path like "img/image.png"

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue